# Norm of $T^n$, where $Tf(x,y) = \begin{cases}f(x+y/b,y), &0<x<1-y/b,\\1/2f(x+y/b-1,y),& 1-y/b<x<1.\end{cases}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $0 < a < b$ and $T\colon L^\infty((0,1)\times (a,b)) \to L^\infty((0,1)\times (a,b))$ be the operator defined by
$$Tf(x,y) = \begin{cases}f(x+\frac yb,y), &0<x<1-\frac yb,\\\frac 12f(x+\frac yb-1,y),& 1-\frac yb<x<1,\end{cases}$$
where $x \in (0,1)$ and $y \in (a,b)$.

> Is it true that
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \|T^n\|}{n} < 0?
> $$

Since $T$ acts in $L^\infty((0,1)\times (a,b))$ and is positive, in order to find $\|T^n\|$ it suffices to find
$$
\sup_{x \in (0,1),\ y \in (a,b)} T^n 1,
$$
where $1$ is a constant function (equals 1 everywhere in $(0,1) \times (a,b)$. However, I it quite difficult for me to find the norm explicitly for $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what $T^n$ does. I will first re-write the definition of $T$.

$$Tf(x,y) = 2^{-\left[x+ \frac yb\right]}f\left (\left\{x+\frac yb\right\},y \right).$$

If we see $(0,1)$ as $\mathbb{R}_{/ \mathbb{Z}}$, then we rotate the first coordinate by $y/b$, and divide by $2$ if we pass $1$. So, applying this transformation $n$ times is equivalent to rotating the first coordinate by $ny/b$, and dividing by $2$ the number of time we have passed $1$. Hence:

$$T^n f(x,y) = 2^{-\left[x+ \frac{ny}{b}\right]}f\left (\left\{x+\frac{ny}{b}\right\},y \right),$$

and:

$$\|T^n\| \leq 2^{-\min_{(x,y) \in (0,1) \times (a,b)} \left[x+ \frac{ny}{b}\right]} \leq 2^{-\left[\frac{na}{b}\right]}.$$

From here you should be able to get a pretty good upper bound on $\|T^n\|$ (and actually, with the help of a similar lower bound, the exact spectral radius of $T$).